Python, kivy, getting not attribute error. Any hand
Im triying to run this basic app to generate graphical node generator, but im getting stuck in this error:
Installed Kivy from anaconda and im also running from visual studio code IDE, but i cannot see where the error is when running the file.
/USER/Documents/python/test/Nueva carpeta (2)/connection_nodes_app.py", line 167, in <module> ConnectionNodesApp().run() File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\kivy\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 955, in run self._run_prepare() File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\kivy\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 925, in _run_prepare root = self.build() File "c:/Users/USER/Documents/python/test/Nueva carpeta (2)/connection_nodes_app.py", line 158, in build network_canvas.add_node(text="Start Node") AttributeError: 'FloatLayout' object has no attribute 'add_node' 
The code is the following:
# connection_nodes_app.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Line, Color
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string(
    """
<Node>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 60
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.size
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 0.8
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        Label:
            id: label
            text: root.text
            size_hint_x: 0.7
        Button:
            text: "Edit"
            size_hint_x: 0.3
            on_release: root.edit_node()

<Network>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        Button:
            text: "Add Node"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            on_release: app.add_node()
        ScrollView:
            NetworkCanvas:
                id: network_layout
                FloatLayout:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: 2000, 2000
"""
)


class Node(Widget):
    def __init__(self, text="Node", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = text
        self.connections = []
        self._dragging = False

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self._dragging = True
            touch.grab(self)
            return True
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self and self._dragging:
            self.center_x += touch.dx
            self.center_y += touch.dy
            for conn in self.connections:
                conn.update()
            return True
        return super().on_touch_move(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self and self._dragging:
            self._dragging = False
            touch.ungrab(self)
            return True
        return super().on_touch_up(touch)

    def edit_node(self):
        popup = Popup(title="Edit Node")
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", spacing=10, padding=10)
        text_input = TextInput(text=self.ids.label.text)
        save_button = Button(text="Save", size_hint_y=None, height=40)

        def save_text(instance):
            self.ids.label.text = text_input.text
            popup.dismiss()

        save_button.bind(on_release=save_text)
        layout.add_widget(text_input)
        layout.add_widget(save_button)
        popup.content = layout
        popup.size_hint = (0.5, 0.5)
        popup.open()


class ConnectionLine:
    def __init__(self, start_node, end_node, canvas):
        self.start_node = start_node
        self.end_node = end_node
        self.canvas = canvas
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
            self.line = Line(
                points=[*self.start_node.center, *self.end_node.center], width=2
            )
        self.start_node.connections.append(self)
        self.end_node.connections.append(self)

    def update(self):
        self.line.points = [*self.start_node.center, *self.end_node.center]


class NetworkCanvas(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.selected_node = None
        self.nodes = []

    def add_node(self, text="New Node", pos=(100, 100)):
        node = Node(text=text, pos=pos)
        self.nodes.append(node)
        self.add_widget(node)

    def connect_nodes(self, node1, node2):
        ConnectionLine(node1, node2, self.canvas)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if super().on_touch_down(touch) is False:
            if touch.button == "right":
                for node in self.nodes:
                    if node.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                        if not self.selected_node:
                            self.selected_node = node
                        else:
                            self.connect_nodes(self.selected_node, node)
                            self.selected_node = None
                        return True
                self.selected_node = None
        return True


class Network(FloatLayout):
    pass


class ConnectionNodesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = Network()
        network_canvas = layout.ids.network_layout.children[0]
        network_canvas.add_node(text="Start Node")
        return layout

    def add_node(self):
        network_canvas = self.root.ids.network_layout.children[0]
        network_canvas.add_node(text="New Node")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ConnectionNodesApp().run()


Tried to change def lines. But no luck.

The line in the error:
network_canvas.add_node(text="Start Node")

is failing because the line before it:
network_canvas = layout.ids.network_layout.children[0]

is setting network_canvas to the FloatLayout that is the first child of the NetworkCanvas. I suspect you actually want network_canvas to refer to the NetworkCanvas object. To do this, just remove the chidren[0]:
network_canvas = layout.ids.network_layout

That will fix the error you are seeing, but you also have the same error in your add_node() method of ConnectionNodesApp. And there are other errors that you will encounter. You can submit that as another post.
